# Google Analytics tracking script remarks/review

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I was looking at the script Google provides you when you want to use Google Analytics.

If you look at the IIF you see it requires 7 arguments, but there are only 5 parameters passed.

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'trackingid', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

They make a nice isogram of the arguments, and this won't break in Javascript, but aren't the 'a' and 'm' arguments obsolete?

I guess the '1 * new Date()' is also a bad practice and getTime would be much nicer. But they probably do this for browser-support. Although getTime is widely supported.

Comment: `a` and `m` are assigned to within the method. They start out as `undefined`, and that way Google doesn't ever have to use a `var` declaration.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid that? I changed the code so the `a` and `m` are declared at the top of the IIF.

Comment: It saves on bytes. And look how much cooler it is to have your tracking script spell `i,s,o,g,r,a,m`!

Comment: Well, true. I still fixed it for my TSLint.

Comment: To answer your question, the parameters are not obsolete (they could not become obsolete since they have not been used in the first place). If anything they are unnecessary.

Comment: More seriously, there is an alternative way to implement the GA loader that has no arguments and saves a few bytes (but might not work with ancient browsers). Documentation here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/#alternative_async_tracking_snippet

Comment: @EikePierstorff Sorry, I misused obsolete, I did mean 'unnecessary'. Thanks for your correction.
I don't really want to save bytes in such an extensive way. I'm writing this in TypeScript, so it gets compiled and minified. If anything, I expanded the code more to be a bit more descriptive.